# How can I make this code concurrency safe?

Tags: swift, swiftui, concurrency

I have the following code written in Swift:

```
protocol Theme {
    var iconColor: Color { get }
}

struct MyTheme: Theme {
   var iconColor: Color = .white
}

class Appearance {
    static var theme: Theme = MyTheme()
}
```

I can use this `Appearance` class in my views to conveniently get the current theme's properties

```
Image("my-icon")
    .foregroundColor(Appearance.theme.iconColor)
```

I enabled `-warn-concurrency` compiler flag in XCode as an experiment to see how many warnings my app produces. This is one of the warnings:

`Reference to static property 'theme' is not concurrency-safe because it involves shared mutable state`

Now I understand why it gives this warning, but how could I change the code so that `theme` is concurrency safe and still as convenient as it is?

I could change `theme` to `static let` but then I would not be able to change the theme of the app during runtime. I also tried combinations of `@MainActor` and `actor Appearance` but they give mixed result with either the same warning or some other error.

**Edit**

`@MainActor class Appearance` gets rid of all the warnings, but consider this:

```
struct FooView: View {
    var iconColor: Color = Appearance.theme.iconColor
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("FooView")
            Image("foo-logo")
                .foregroundColor(iconColor)
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will give an error: `Main actor-isolated static property 'theme' can not be referenced from a non-isolated context`

Comment: `@MainActor class Appearance` should work. Surely you have tried that? What error did it give you?

Comment: @Sweeper I edited the question to explain what happens

Comment: Let the var to a let. As is there is no way for SwiftUI to know when it has changed anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the warning, you can just add `@MainActor` to the `Appearance` class. You would also need to mark `FooView` with `@MainActor` if you are using it outside of `body`, because `body` is `MainActor`-isolated, but `FooView` is not.

That said, this won't work in practice. SwiftUI won't know that `Appearance.theme` has changed and update your views' colors accordingly. The SwitUI way of implementing such a "theme" system is to use an `EnvironmentObject`.

```
class Appearance: ObservableObject {
    @Published var theme: Theme = MyTheme()
}
```

```
struct YourRootView: View {
    // write this in every view that needs to access the theme
    @EnvironmentObject var appearance: Appearance
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Foo")
            .foregroundColor(appearance.theme.iconColor)
    }
}
```

When you create `YourRootView`, give it a new `Appearance` object.

```
@main
struct FooApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            YourRootView()
                .environmentObject(Appearance())
        }
    }
}
```

Now SwiftUI can observe the changes to the `theme` property.

Comment: Yup, using `@EnvironmentObject` and `@ObservableObject` was the solution I had in mind. I just wanted to avoid typing `@EnvironmentObject var appearance: Appearance` in all of my views. But I guess there is no other viable solution